# Oracle access via SSIS

Tags: ssis, oracle11g, oracle10g

In a server ex: 111.21.11.abc has oracle client. There is a oracle database.
Now I am in a server ex: 222.21.44.xyz from where i want to access that oracle server via SSIS package.

How can I do this? Do i need to install oracle client in the xyz server? Or only configure it via the SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

You can install SSIS connectors for Oracle
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29284